# How to install python dependencies for dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, requirements.txt

I have a very small python dataflow package, the structure of package looks like this

```
.
├── __pycache__
├── pubsubtobigq.py
├── requirements.txt
└── venv
```

the content of `requirements.txt` is

```
protobuf==3.11.2
protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5
```

I ran my pipline using this code

```
python -m pubsubtobigq \
  --input_topic "projects/project_name/topics/topic_name" \
  --job_name "job_name" \
  --output "gs://mybucket/wordcount/outputs" \
  --runner DataflowRunner \
  --project "project_name"  \
  --region "us-central1" \
  --temp_location "gs://mybucket/tmp/" \
  --staging_location "gs://mybucket/staging" \
  --requirements_file requirements.txt \
  --streaming True
```

The code which is using this library is like

```
from protobuf_to_dict import protobuf_to_dict

def parse_proto(message):
    dictinoary = protobuf_to_dict(message)
```

But this line fails saying that `protobuf_to_dict` is an unknown symbol. Even if i try with google built in method `MessageToDict` from `google.protobuf.json_format` i get the same error.

How can i fix this? I need to install either of these libarries

**EDIT**

Error message when i used `MessageToDict` from `google.protobuf.json_format`

```
Error processing instruction -31. Original traceback is Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 813, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File 
"apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 449, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "/Users/username/repos/
dataflow-pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1415, in 
wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)] File "/Users/username/repos/dataflow-pipeline/pubsubtobigq.py", line 
16, in parse_proto NameError: name 'MessageToDict' is not defined During handling of the above 
exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 143, in _execute response 
= task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", 
line 193, in lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File "/usr/local/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 291, in do_instruction 
request.instruction_id) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/
sdk_worker.py", line 317, in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 675, 
in process_bundle data.transform_id].process_encoded(data.data) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/
site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 146, in process_encoded 
self.output(decoded_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 258, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/
operations.py", line 259, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File 
"apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 146, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/
worker/operations.py", line 596, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File 
"apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 597, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 809, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 815, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 882, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "/usr/local/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/init.py", line 421, in raise_with_traceback raise 
exc.with_traceback(traceback) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 813, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 449, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "/Users/username/repos/
dataflow-pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1415, in 
wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)] File 
"/Users/username/repos/dataflow-pipeline/pubsubtobigq.py", line 16, in parse_proto NameError: 
name 'MessageToDict' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-23']
```

Error Message when i used `protobuf_to_dict`

```
Error processing instruction -32. Original traceback is Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 813, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File 
"apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 449, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "/Users/username/repos/
dataflow-pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1415, in 
wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)] File "/Users/username/repos/dataflow-pipeline/pubsubtobigq.py", line 
21, in parse_proto NameError: name 'protobuf_to_dict' is not defined During handling of the above 
exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 143, in _execute response 
= task() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", 
line 193, in lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) File "/usr/local/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 291, in do_instruction 
request.instruction_id) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/
sdk_worker.py", line 317, in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 675, 
in process_bundle data.transform_id].process_encoded(data.data) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/
site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 146, in process_encoded 
self.output(decoded_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 258, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File "apache_beam/runners/worker/
operations.py", line 259, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File 
"apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 146, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive File "apache_beam/runners/
worker/operations.py", line 596, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File 
"apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 597, in 
apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 809, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 815, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", 
line 882, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File "/usr/local/lib/
python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/init.py", line 421, in raise_with_traceback raise 
exc.with_traceback(traceback) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 813, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 449, in 
apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "/Users/username/repos/
dataflow-pipeline/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1415, in 
wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)] File "/Users/username/repos/dataflow-pipeline/pubsubtobigq.py", line 
21, in parse_proto NameError: name 'protobuf_to_dict' is not defined [while running 
'generatedPtransform-22']
```

Comment: Please add the error message you're seeing

Comment: Can you try again by using double equal signs in your requirements.txt file ? Because not it is not formatted properly and will not be installed.

Mainly the on the `protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5`

Comment: @GeorgesLorré: It didn't make any difference. Also, I have updated my question with exact error message

Comment: Have you tried to run the pipeline by using `DirectRunner`? Did it worked? Have you tried to install locally protobuf via `pip install`?

Comment: could you try to move the import statement into your ParDo function or add '--save_main_session True' while submitting pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow workers cannot look into global dependencies  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors

As suggested by quimiluzon@, try if your job works with `DirectRunner`. If so, this might work:

```
def parse_proto(message):
    from protobuf_to_dict import protobuf_to_dict
    dictinoary = protobuf_to_dict(message)
```