# Python libraries not visible in dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, setuptools

(this is not a duplicate of my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993785/how-to-install-python-dependencies-for-dataflow). i am trying a different approach using `setup.py` which is different from existing approach which was by using `requirements.txt`)

My project is setup like this

```
.
├── __pycache__
├── eventstream-to-bigq-main.py
└── setup.py
```

the `setup.py` file looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    "protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5",
    "protobuf==3.11.2",
]

setup(
    name="eventstream-to-bigq",
    version="1.0",
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

finally i am trying to use these 2 libraries like this

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
from protobuf_to_dict import protobuf_to_dict

def parse_proto(message):
    try:
        dictobj = MessageToDict(message)
        logging.info("google lib", dictobj)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("google-lib failed")
        logging.error(e)

    try:
        s = protobuf_to_dict(message)
        logging.info("third party", s)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("protobuf-to-dict failed")
        logging.error(e)
```

Even after this, I am getting following errors

`message: "name 'MessageToDict' is not defined"` and `message: "name 'protobuf_to_dict' is not defined"`.

I monitored the logs when the image was booting up and i could see following log lines

```
I 2020-01-31T01:28:22.446626952Z 2020/01/31 01:28:22   Building wheel for protobuf3-to-dict (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

I 2020-01-31T01:28:22.443982764Z 2020/01/31 01:28:22   Building wheel for protobuf3-to-dict (setup.py): started
```

I could see similar log lines for `protobuf` as well. The only warning that i see around here is `WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.`

Even after all this installation, My code still fails

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention that i am running this using this command

```
python -m eventstream-to-bigq-main \
    --input_topic "projects/project_name/topics/topic_name" \
    --job_name "rawdata-to-bigq-2" \
    --output "gs://bucketname/wordcount/outputs" \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project "project_name"  \
    --region "us-central1" \
    --temp_location "gs://bucketname/tmp/" \
    --staging_location "gs://bucketname/staging" \
    --setup_file ./setup.py \
    --streaming True
```

Answer (score 0):

The `protobuf` package is already installed on Dataflow workers, what you can check in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#beam-2x-python). The only package, you need to install is `protobuf3-to-dict`.

Firstly install package on your machine:

```
pip3 install protobuf3-to-dict
```

Then, check out which packages are installed on your machine:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This command creates a `requirements.txt` file that lists all packages that are installed on your machine. Please, edit the `requirements.txt` file and leave only the packages that were installed from PyPI. Delete all packages that are not relevant to your code.

So in your case, `requirements.txt` looks like that:

```
protobuf3-to-dict==0.1.5
```

Run your pipeline with the following command-line option, which will use file to install additional dependencies onto the remote workers:

```
--requirements_file requirements.txt
```

I have done some tests, and error disappeared. I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: I have already tried that and still getting similar errors. See my other question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993785/how-to-install-python-dependencies-for-dataflow

Comment: Which SDK, python version do you use? Could you provide also what argument you use when running a pipeline?

Comment: Updated my original question. I haven't explicitly put any python sdk for pipeline, whatever google has for default?

Comment: As you can see here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status there are different SDK version, I need to know which one you are using